# Problems with Devtools Package

Tags: r, github, dplyr, rstudio, devtools

I recently had to upgrade to a 64 bit linux mint and redownload rstudio. When I try to use install_github I get this:

```
 > devtools::install_github("rstudio/dplyr")
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/dplyr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/dplyr/zipball/master
Installation failed: Not Found (404)
```

This is a small part of a larger problem I have been having with downloading packages in general. install.packages is not working for most packages(zero-exit status problem). dependencies=TRUE is not working, either. I am not sure if it is related to my linux mint system, but when I have tried putting this in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcur14-openss1-dev libxm12-dev
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package libcur14-openss1-dev
  E: Unable to locate package libxm12-dev
```

I only include this last part because I am not sure if the problem is with rstudio or linux. If the problem is linux then I am willing to go somewhere else if necessary.

Comment: There is no github repository at https://github.com/rstudio/dplyr. Do you mean https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr by chance? Also, in the names of your apt-packages you use a numeral `1` instead of an `l` for some reason. Use `libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `libxml2-dev` instead.

Comment: It looks like that was certainly a step in the right direction, however now I am just getting an error saying it can't install Rcpp, bindrcpp, and tibble(dependencies for dplyr) from github.